# Excel Macro deleting first row if empty

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue where the macro is deleting the entire column if the first row is empty.  Is there any way of finding the first available row with data?  I'm assuming the issue is with naming "A2" as the range?

```
Sub PrepForUpload()

Dim rowNumber As Integer

Sheets("Initiatives").Select

ActiveSheet.Range("a2").Select
    While (Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)) <> "")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Wend
rowNumber = ActiveCell.Row

ActiveSheet.Range(rowNumber & ":65536").Select
Selection.Clear

Range("A2").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: Would love to be able to see who votes down legitimate questions like this one too.  Is there a way to see who gives negative votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the select makes your macro slower. If you're trying to to clear everything after the last filled A cell, try this instead

```
Sub PrepForUpload()

Dim rowNumber As Integer

with Sheets("Initiatives")

    if len(.cells(2,1))=0 then 
        rowNumber=.cells(2,1).end(xldown).end(xldown).row + 1
    else
        rowNumber=.cells(2,1).end(xldown).row + 1
    end if

    .rows(rowNumber & ":" & .rows.count).Clear

end with

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: This didn't do anything, nutsch

Comment: It will not do anything if you have no data after the last row. What are you trying to achieve with that macro?

Comment: The data will be uploaded into Access.  The original macro works fine if row A2 is populated with data.  However, if row2 is empty, the original macro will then delete the entire column.  I'd like the macro to skip to the first row of data, whether it starts in "a2" or "a3" or "a4" etc

Comment: Is a1 empty or is it a header?

Comment: The issue I'm still having.  If Row A2 is blank, but the rows A3 & below have data, how would I be able to select all the data below blank A2 and then move up into cell a2.  This is a pretty complex macro/code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17162/discussion-between-nutsch-and-rcoy1978)